# Row Number in SSRS gives random number because of grouping

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

In SSRS when I am grouping by the Risk Description column. So the  Rank  column is completely messed up. I tried expression `=RowNumber(Nothing)` but still - no luck 
[image]

My data in SSMS looks like on a picture below.
[image]

What would be the workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression made the job:

```
=RunningValue(CountDistinct("YourTableName"),Count,"YourTableName")
```